# Java ClassFormatError: Method "<error>" class has illegal signature

Tags: java, static

Im getting error on line 1 and line 2. Line 1 says illegal start of expression.
I dont understand why line 1 is illegal

```
public class MyArt {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        MyArt m = new MyArt();
        m.amethod();
    }

    public void amethod() {
        static int i; // line 1
        System.out.println (i); // line 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot decalre static field inside method:

```
public class MyArt {

        public static void main(String argv[]) {
              MyArt m = new MyArt();
              m.amethod();
        }
        //you can very well have non-static method since you are 
        //calling it through MyArt object m
        public void amethod() { 

             int i=0; // REMOVED STATIC, otherwise program won't compile 
             System.out.println (i); // line 2, if not initialized compilation will fail where the variable is refrenced

        }
    }
```